# Move a button with a particular class to the end of the unordered list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list which has a button that renders different colors. The button can be a normal button or can have a class "discontinued". My requirement is that, I want to move the button having class "discontinued" to the end of the unordered list. Please find below the markup that renders the list.

```
<ul>
<li>
    <span class="koh-product-variant" data-koh-color="Ice Grey">
    <button class="koh-product-color discontinued" disabled="disabled" data-hasqtip="swatch00">
    <img src="https://kohler.scene7.com/is/image/PAWEB/swatch_95?$SwatchSS$" width="40" height="40" alt=""><span class="label">Ice Grey</span>
    </button>
    </span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="koh-product-variant" data-koh-color="Almond">
    <button class="koh-product-color discontinued" disabled="disabled" data-hasqtip="swatch01">
    <img src="https://kohler.scene7.com/is/image/PAWEB/swatch_47?$SwatchSS$" width="40" height="40" alt=""><span class="label">Almond</span>
</button>
</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="koh-product-variant koh-selected-variant" data-koh-color="White">
    <button class="koh-product-color" data-hasqtip="swatch02">
    <img src="https://kohler.scene7.com/is/image/PAWEB/swatch_0?$SwatchSS$" width="40" height="40" alt=""><span class="label">White</span>
</button>
</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="koh-product-variant" data-koh-color="Biscuit">
    <button class="koh-product-color" data-hasqtip="swatch03">
    <img src="https://kohler.scene7.com/is/image/PAWEB/swatch_96?$SwatchSS$" width="40" height="40" alt=""><span class="label">Biscuit</span>
</button>
</span>
</li>
```

I wan to move the entire li, with button which has class discontinued to the end of the ul. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why you don't change the order in the HTML? — I don't quite understand what do you want. Try to explain a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`AppendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li button.discontinued').closest('li').appendTo('ul');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="koh-product-variant" data-koh-color="Ice Grey">
    <button class="koh-product-color discontinued" disabled="disabled" data-hasqtip="swatch00">
    <img src="https://kohler.scene7.com/is/image/PAWEB/swatch_95?$SwatchSS$" width="40" height="40" alt=""><span class="label">Ice Grey</span>
    </button>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="koh-product-variant" data-koh-color="Almond">
    <button class="koh-product-color discontinued" disabled="disabled" data-hasqtip="swatch01">
    <img src="https://kohler.scene7.com/is/image/PAWEB/swatch_47?$SwatchSS$" width="40" height="40" alt=""><span class="label">Almond</span>
    </button>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="koh-product-variant koh-selected-variant" data-koh-color="White">
    <button class="koh-product-color" data-hasqtip="swatch02">
    <img src="https://kohler.scene7.com/is/image/PAWEB/swatch_0?$SwatchSS$" width="40" height="40" alt=""><span class="label">White</span>
    </button>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="koh-product-variant" data-koh-color="Biscuit">
    <button class="koh-product-color" data-hasqtip="swatch03">
    <img src="https://kohler.scene7.com/is/image/PAWEB/swatch_96?$SwatchSS$" width="40" height="40" alt=""><span class="label">Biscuit</span>
    </button>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works bang on. I was just struggling to write this JQuery function. I was aware of the appendTo function, but was always selecting the wrong selector to append too. You are the best! Simple and elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take that `<li class="discontinued">` at the end of the `<ul>` then just change its sequence like below:

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span class="koh-product-variant koh-selected-variant" data-koh-color="White">
            <button class="koh-product-color" data-hasqtip="swatch02">
            <img src="https://kohler.scene7.com/is/image/PAWEB/swatch_0?$SwatchSS$" width="40" height="40" alt=""><span class="label">White</span>
        </button>
        </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="koh-product-variant" data-koh-color="Biscuit">
            <button class="koh-product-color" data-hasqtip="swatch03">
            <img src="https://kohler.scene7.com/is/image/PAWEB/swatch_96?$SwatchSS$" width="40" height="40" alt=""><span class="label">Biscuit</span>
        </button>
        </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="koh-product-variant" data-koh-color="Ice Grey">
            <button class="koh-product-color discontinued" disabled="disabled" data-hasqtip="swatch00">
            <img src="https://kohler.scene7.com/is/image/PAWEB/swatch_95?$SwatchSS$" width="40" height="40" alt=""><span class="label">Ice Grey</span>
            </button>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="koh-product-variant" data-koh-color="Almond">
            <button class="koh-product-color discontinued" disabled="disabled" data-hasqtip="swatch01">
            <img src="https://kohler.scene7.com/is/image/PAWEB/swatch_47?$SwatchSS$" width="40" height="40" alt=""><span class="label">Almond</span>
        </button>
        </span>
        </li>
   </ul>
```

or else you need to give css like below :

```
.discontinued {
   position: "absolute";
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: This code snippet was copied from developer tools. The data that is coming is dynamic, and I don't have direct control to it. It is basically a forEach loop. So your solution is not going to help me

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to add the `discontinued` class to the parent `li` then you could try using the flexbox `order` property.

Checkout this codepen: 
https://codepen.io/cmbonin/pen/QQLXmR

Comment: I tried flex, but it affects the layout of the other items in the container. So I was mostly looking for a JQuery solution. Thanks anyways @user1494917.